# Android soft keyboard won't dissappear

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

So i've got an EditText which is disabled initially. When i press a button it enables it, and automatically opens the soft keyboard.

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

mgr.showSoftInput(etToDelete, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

After i enter some text in it, i press the EditText which should make it disable again and hide the opened keyboard.

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(((EditText)view).getWindowToken(), 0);
```

BUT, what it does is very quickly close and then reopens it. MY GUESS is when you normally press an EditText it opens the keboard, so in this case even though i close it, it reopens it because of that :(

What is the solution? I've tried a couple of methods by which i stop the keyboard from showing when an EditText is pressed, but i was unsuccessfull, if someone could offer me a concrete example of how this should be made, i'd be grateful.

Comment: can u post you code more briefly on listeners, so that we can find the prob clearly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same problem I solved so:

first create a class KeyBoardManager:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

public class KeyBoardManager {

    public KeyBoardManager(Context context) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    try{Thread.sleep(100);}catch (Exception e) {}
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(!imm.isAcceptingText()){
                                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

and in method onCreate of first activity you create a new instance of KeyBoardManager like:

```
public class Main extends Activity {    
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new KeyBoardManager(this);
    }
}
```

and when your edittext is draw in screen for the firs time you call:]

```
(new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    editText.requestFocus();
    editText.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN , 0, 0, 0));
    editText.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP , 0, 0, 0));
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

Every method for hiding keyboard when starting fragment didnt work for me, but this made it, so try it out maybe

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```